# Php - Select items from array by keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this PHP array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 64 [img] => 20090refe61fr705-est-Ue3hM [rank] => 1 )
[1] => Array ( [id] => 64 [img] => 200frferf612fr05-stanze-kQakO [rank] => 2 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 64 [img] => 20090306123705-stanze-zgYg9 [rank] => 3 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 981 [img] => 200923rfrtggr4515-est-2SpjN [rank] => 1 )
```

I would like, print in a cycle foreach the item [img] where [id] is equal to 981 (for example)

How can I do?

Comment: What have you tried? "_I would like, print in a cycle foreach the item [img] where [id] is equal to 981_" = `foreach(..) { if (..['id'] == 981) { print ..['img']; } }`, you already have everything you need

Comment: I want select from the array (that is very long) only the items with specific ID. I want avoid every time hundreds on cycles...

Comment: Is the id unique? Then use it as key for the item - otherwise you'll always have to iterate over the whole list

Comment: no, [id] isn't a unique field; I'm trying array_search

Comment: You could still use the id as key and have it save an array of items that share this id. This way or another: you should change the structure to increase performance

Comment: I have only one array with every items; I need to divide this array on X by the value of the [id].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like, print in a cycle foreach the item [img] where [id] is equal to 981 (for example)

If you wanted to search a particular `id` inside your example array and return the matching `img`. There is no need for an `array_search`. A good ol' foreach should suffice.

Consider this example:

```
$values = array( array('id' => 64, 'img' => '20090refe61fr705-est-Ue3hM', 'rank' => 1), array('id' => 64, 'img' => '200frferf612fr05-stanze-kQakO', 'rank' => 2), array('id' => 64, 'img' => '20090306123705-stanze-zgYg9', 'rank' => 3), array('id' => 981, 'img' => '200923rfrtggr4515-est-2SpjN', 'rank' => 1),);

$needle = 981;
$search_results = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    if($needle == $value['id']) {
        $search_results[] = $value['img'];
        // or echo $value['img'];
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($search_results);
echo '</pre>';
```

[**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eIX4mC)